# Making an AJAX call to get data from a search form result to render.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am making a stock application and basically the user needs to enter a ticker and after going through the ajax call it will return the instance variable containing the price, ticker, and name. It will also render right below the search bar.

here is a pic of the UI
[image]

Here is the model

```
<div id="stock-lookup">
    <h3>Search for Stocks</h3>
    <%= form_tag search_stocks_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: 'stock-lookup-form' do %>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= text_field_tag :stock,
        params[:stock],
        placeholder: 'Stock Ticker Symbol',
        autofocus: true,
        class: 'form-control search-box input-lg' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success') do %>
            <i class='fa fa-search'></i> Look up a stock
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
<% if @stock %>
<div id="stock-lookup-results" class="well results-block">
    <strong>Symbol:</strong> <%= @stock.ticker %>
    <strong>Name:</strong> <%= @stock.name %>
    <strong>Price:</strong> <%= @stock.price %>
</div>
<div id="stock-lookup-errors"></div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Here is the controller

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController

    def search
        if params[:stock]
            @stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(params[:stock])
            @stock ||= Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
        end
        if @stock
            puts @stock.price
            render partial: 'lookup'
        else
            render status: :not_found, nothing: true
        end
    end

end
```

when I puts puts @stock.price, I am getting the information I want. It then proceeds to render the page I want, but it doesnt seem to get me the information which is rendered in an erb file with an if condition that says if @stock, render the necessary information.

here is the view to give you an idea of what I am talking about.

```
<div id="stock-lookup">
    <h3>Search for Stocks</h3>
    <%= form_tag search_stocks_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: 'stock-lookup-form' do %>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= text_field_tag :stock,
        params[:stock],
        placeholder: 'Stock Ticker Symbol',
        autofocus: true,
        class: 'form-control search-box input-lg' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success') do %>
            <i class='fa fa-search'></i> Look up a stock
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
<% if @stock %>
<div id="stock-lookup-results" class="well results-block">
    <strong>Symbol:</strong> <%= @stock.ticker %>
    <strong>Name:</strong> <%= @stock.name %>
    <strong>Price:</strong> <%= @stock.price %>
</div>
<div id="stock-lookup-errors"></div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I also am making an ajax call in a separate js file which seems to be doing its job.

```
var init_stock_lookup;

init_stock_lookup = function() {
    $('#stock-lookup-form').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status) {
         $('#stock-lookup').append(data);
         init_stock_lookup();
    })
}

    $('#stock-lookupform').on('ajax:error',function(event, xhr, status, error){
        $('#stock-lookup-results').replaceWith(' ');
        $('#stock-lookup-errors').replaceWith('Stock was not found.')
    });

$(document).ready( function(){
    init_stock_lookup();
})
```

def not a rails or ruby master, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Зелёный I deleted both answers, because they are both wrong. Sorry

Comment: what is the ajax code for? you are using `turbolinks`? why are you using `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening in your case when you call `render partial: 'lookup'` in your controller action it is giving the code in response you can check that on browser's developer console but it doesn't know what to do of that response like either append it prepend it replace any HTML from the DOM etc etc.

Try this:

In your controller action write this:

```
def search
  if params[:stock]
    @stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(params[:stock])
    @stock ||= Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

In your `app/views/stocks` create a file `search.js.erb` and in it write the code:

```
<% if @stock %>
  $('body').html("<%= j render partial: 'lookup' %>");
<% end %>
```

You will definetely need to change `$('body').html` to some relevant selector in your application.

Hope this helps.